# Rails strong parameters - Any advantage to cacheing the results of .require and .permit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, parameters, actioncontroller

Sorry if this question is a bit on the esoteric side. I'm using strong parameters in a Rails controller:

```
  def license_params
    params.require(:license).permit(:name, :rank)
  end
```

Typically, `license_params` is only used one time in an action, such as, `License.where(license_params)`.

However, this controller does some sneaky manipulations on the params. As a result, I call `license_params` from several different methods. Ignoring whether that's a good idea or not, I decided to cache the response from `.require.permit`:

```
  def license_params
    @license_params ||= params.require(:license).permit(:name, :rank)
  end
```

I realize any performance gains are beyond negligible, but this is a very high-traffic endpoint.

Does anyone have an opinion if this is useful, irrelevant, or redundant to what ActionController::Parameters is already doing?

Comment: Both methods just return new instances of ActionController::Parameters. My opinion is to focus on stuff that actually matters like database queries or refactorying that method so that it doesn't need to "do some sneaky manipulations on the params".

Comment: I don't think that is correct @max.  The second way would not create a new instance, in the same controller action.  It would create it at most once per controller action.

Comment: @marlin pierce I'm aware of how memorization works - it's still just premature optimization and completely inconsequential.

Comment: @max someone reading your comment might not know and think it returned new instances of ActionController::Parameters on every call.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Marlin and max. I agree on all points.